# Cant change a gridview cell in C# , getting datagrid view default Error Dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to change some columns values in a `DataGridView` in my C# windows application,    But when i try  to assign the new value, i get a pop up error window which says:

> DataGridView default Error Dialog
>
> the following exception occurred in the DataGridView :...

Here is the screen shot showing this pop up window which is shown even inside a try block!
[image]
This is how I am doing it, first the gridview is populated and then i try to change some columns values , which are numbers, to show with a thousand separated numeric values. for example instead of 780000 , i get 780,000 !

```
private static string Test(string number)
{
  try
   {
     gridview.DataSource = DBAPI.ExecuteSqlFunction(function, new string[] { CurrentSourceID });
    //format price
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gridview.Rows)
    {
       row.Cells[2].Value = GetFormattedNumber(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Replace(",",""));
    }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SaveAndShowLog(ex);
    }
}
    public static string GetFormattedNumber(string number)
    {
       try
        {
            return string.Format("{0:N0}", Int64.Parse(number));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SaveAndShowLog(ex);
            return  number;
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried setting the cells `Format` property to "N0" instead?

Comment: What is the value of `row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Replace(",","")` ? I assume you get _FormatException_ on this line..

Comment: or wait: you HAVE "780,000" but WANT "780000"? then the error should occur when the cell values are first set and not in this code

Comment: This is probably a culture problem. Some use , to clarify big numbers, some use , to specify parts of a whole. Check that your cultures match.

Comment: @olydis: actually the number in row.Cells[2].Value is 780000, that replace is for future calls , so that i always get the number without commas and pass then to the GetFormattedNumber method for being formatted correctly.

Comment: @Hossein I have removed my answer since I was thinking the solution was the first comment, but I really think now using `cellFormatting` is a possible solution for what you are attempting to do. I will update it and undeleted it.

Comment: I was going to accept that as the answer ! i was surprised why you deleted it in first place! in any case thanks alot and im waiting for your answer ;)

Comment: @Hossein Done!, and glad I could help ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the error message you need to handle the [`DataGridView.DataError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.dataerror.aspx) event.
See sample from the link.

You could use the `DataGridViewCellFormatting` event to format the value, and don't try to directly replace the value with a string value since it will raise an error anyway.

```
private static string Test(string number)
{
    try 
    {
        gridview.DataSource = DBAPI.ExecuteSqlFunction(function, new string[] { CurrentSourceID });
        gridview.CellFormatting += gridView_CellFormatting;
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        SaveAndShowLog(ex);
    }
}

public static string GetFormattedNumber(string number)
{
    try
    {
        return string.Format("{0:N0}", Int64.Parse(number));
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        SaveAndShowLog(ex);
        return number;
    }
}

private static void gridView_CellFormatting(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
    {
        object val = gridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value;
        if ((val != null) && !object.ReferenceEquals(val, DBNull.Value))
        {
            e.Value = GetFormattedNumber(val.ToString().Replace(",", ""));
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }

    }
}
```